# How can I combine two jQuery selectors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following selectors:

```
$('#menu a[href^="/C"]').live('click', function (event) { } )
$('#menu a[href^="/T"]').live('click', function (event) { } )
```

One selects href that starts with /C and the other /T

Is there a way that I can combine these?

Comment: The selectors are exactly the same

Comment: oops. Changed it now :-)

Comment: The comma answers are all correct but if you find yourself combining more than two you'd probably be better off using a data-* attribute or class and selecting on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The selectors you gave were exactly the same, but in general all you have to do is comma delimit the two selectors like the following:

```
$('#firstSelector, #secondSelector');
```

For more information check out the jquery site on [mutiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

**Edit:**

This should be what you are looking for:

```
$('#menu a[href^="/C"], #menu a[href^="/T"]').live('click',function(e){});
```

Answer (score 5):

Multiple jquery selectors can be separated by commas:

```
$('#menu a[href^="/C"], #menu a[href^="/T"]').live('click',function(e){});
```