# combine jquery .on() on multiple divs

Tags: jquery

**I have this:**

```
$('#MyDiv1').on({

   mouseenter: function () { SomeFunction(); },
   mouseleave: function () { SomeOtherFunction(); }

}, '.SomeClass');

$('#MyDiv2').on({

   mouseenter: function () { SomeFunction(); },
   mouseleave: function () { SomeOtherFunction(); }

}, '.SomeClass');
```

Basically, the handlers are the same for both `MyDiv1` and `MyDiv2`.

How do I combine them into one handler for both?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery same click event for multiple elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements) and [How can I combine two jQuery selectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458994/how-can-i-combine-two-jquery-selectors) and [potentially others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+combine+selectors). Take the time to read the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/), it's worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#MyDiv1, #MyDiv2').on({

   mouseenter: function () { SomeFunction(); },
   mouseleave: function () { SomeOtherFunction(); },

}, '.SomeClass');
```