# jquery: shorthand - display none for several id

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, block, hidden

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I combine two jQuery selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458994/how-can-i-combine-two-jquery-selectors)

I have a working code

```
$('#block1').css("display", "none");
$('#block2').css("display", "none");
$('#block3').css("display", "none");
```

I believe it could be written in one string. How to do that?

I believe it could be done with several options and expected results, so here are more additional details if needed:

it is OK set `display: none;` for all ids that start with the word `block`, like `block123` or `blockabc4` (all ids that start with `block` are only `#block1`, `#block2` and `#block3`).
The current value of `display` property before the code apply is `block`.

Comment: Do they have a common class?

Comment: .hide() is even shorter.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#block1, #block2, #block3').css("display", "none");
```

or if you've got a lot of blocks with different endings:

```
$('[id^=block]').css('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the comma operator to group different selectors, like this:

```
$('#block1,#block2,#block3').css("display", "none");
```

Alternatively you could use the jQuery [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to select all elements whose `id` attribute starts with `block` string, like this:

```
$('[id^=block]').css("display", "none");
```

Besides, `.hide()` is a shortcut to `.css("display", "none")` , so the above code could just be:

```
$('#block1,#block2,#block3').hide();
$('[id^=block]').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
$('[id^=block]').css("display", "none");
```

But it is much better if you use some sort of common hook like a class or descent from an ancestor to target them.

Answer (score 0):

Include all element with ID beginning with "block"

```
$('[id^="block"]').css("display", "none");
```